# Difference between class $\{x\mid x\in Y\}$ and $Y$ with $Y$ being a set?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Consider $X,Y$ 2 sets. One wants to define $X\cap Y$. There is no guarantee that $X\cap Y$ will be a set on the formal level.

Consider class $C=\{x\mid x\in Y\}$ where $x\in Y$ is treated as property $P(x)$. From separation axiom, one deduces $C\cap X$ saying $x\in C\cap X$ iff $x\in X$ and $x\in Y$. Hence from extensionality, one deduces $C\cap X=X\cap Y$.

However, it seems that $x\in C$ iff $x\in Y$ as well. Thus I deduce $C=Y$ to start with. This indicates $C$ is a set to start with.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Did I miss something critical here as the book seems implying class is necessary? The book says one consequence of separation axiom is that intersection and difference between 2 sets are sets which allows defining such operations. When I was trying to see this, I defined the class first and then intersect with $X$ as prescribed by property $P(x)=x\in Y$. The difference is done similarly by replacing $P(x)=x\not\in Y$. In either case, I do not see necessity of usage of class.

Ref. Set Theory, Jech Pt I, Chpt 1, Separation Axioms.

Comment: I must be missing something.  If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, isn't it necessarily the case that $\{y \in Y~|~y \in X \} (= X \cap Y)$ is also a set?

Comment: @RobertShore That is the case for sure after application of extension axiom. I am not sure whether I can drop application of extension axiom application to conclude it is a set.(i.e. Skip application of extension axiom and conclude directly it being a set.)

Comment: Yes, the class $C$ in this case is a set, and it is equal to $Y$; some classes are sets. The point is that you simply *cannot apply separation* unless you come up with the right $P(x)$, i.e. the right class, in Jech's treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to apply *Separation* (see [Jech, page 8](https://books.google.it/books?id=CZb-CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA8)) :

> > $∀X \ ∃Z \ (C \cap X = Z)$.
>
> Thus the intersection of a class $C$ with any set is a set.

Being a class, $C$ is $\{ x : \varphi(x) \}$ for some formula $\varphi(x)$; thus, we need the following instance of *Separation* :

> $∃Z \ ∀u \ (u∈Z ↔ u∈X ∧ \varphi(u) )$.

Obviously, it holds also with $C=Y$ a set, because every set is also a class : $C = \{ x : x \in Y \}$.